# How do I get this VBScript to terminate when no files match the criteria?

Tags: vbscript

I've modified an existing script I found to meet my needs, but it runs perpetually.

Basically, the script checks through folders below the specified path and deletes any files older than 7 days with the file extension `.done`.

I cannot get it to terminate once it has renamed all files with matching criteria. Any ideas?

```
Set args = WScript.Arguments

For Each arg In args
  t = Split(arg, "=")
  If IsNumeric(t(1)) Then
    v = arg
  Else
    v = t(0) & "=" & """" & t(1) & """"
  End If
  Execute (v)
Next

FileTooOld = DateAdd("d", -7, Now())

Set fso = WScript.CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do Until False
  ShowSubFolders fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Redacted\Desktop\Test")
Loop

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
  WScript.Echo "* " & Folder & "\" '& subfolder.name
  Set files = Folder.Files
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each file In files
    If LCase(Right(file.Name, 5)) = ".done" Then
      realfile = folder & "\" & Left(file.Name, Len(file.Name) - 5)

      If Not fso.FileExists(realfile) And file.DateLastModified < FileTooOld Then
        WScript.Echo realfile & ".done"
        file.Delete
      End If
    End If
  Next
  On Error Goto 0
  For Each Subfolder In Folder.SubFolders
    WScript.Echo "** " & subfolder & "\" '& subfolder.Name
    ShowSubFolders Subfolder
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You keep calling `ShowSubFolders()` in an infinite loop (`Do Until False ... Loop`). Remove the loop and just call the procedure once if you want the script to terminate after doing the cleanup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per me , the below is an unnecessary loop. The looping part is already taken care of inside the sub.

```
Do Until False        
    ShowSubFolders fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Redacted\Desktop\Test")
loop
```

Instead of the above loop, just call the sub ShowSubFolders  and comment the loop like below and your problem should be solved. Please let me know if this helps.

```
'Do Until False        
    ShowSubFolders fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Redacted\Desktop\Test")
'loop
```

Comment: That appears to have worked perfectly. Thank you very much for the help. :)